# PHPMailer EHLO Error

Tags: email, smtp, phpmailer

I have a problem for a couple of days ago me going crazy, I have a script that sends mails using phpMailer and arsys.

The fact is that the overnight stops working, check the code and seems fine, it's more, it works correctly if I run it from the test server that comes through another IP.

I found that the server was not on any spam blackList and found the reference to be to a PBL, me worry about removing it from there.

Anyway, I still can not send mail from that server and both my other test script I programmed work correctly on development server but not on the production server.

The error that is specifically this

```
SMTP -> ERROR: EHLO not accepted from server: 
SMTP -> ERROR: HELO not accepted from server: 220 ESMTP Postfix smtp-04.servidoresdns.net 
SMTP -> ERROR: AUTH not accepted from server: 250-250-llsg993-a04.servidoresdns.net PIPELINING 250-SIZE 51200000 250-ETRN 250-250-STARTTLS AUTH DIGEST-MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN 250-AUTH = DIGEST MD5 CRAM-MD5 LOGIN PLAIN 250-250 8BITMIME ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
```

It says it can not authenticate the credentials are fine but since the same script from another server goes perfectly.

Also came through a tcptraceroute to port 25 SMTP server.

Only strange thing I see is that when running

```
tcptraceroute p 25 smtp.miservidor.com
```

He says:

Sorry, Local Requested port is already in use. Use P, instead of p, to override.

But after using P instead of p and functions

Anyone shed me some light on this?

Who may be filtering my IP address ??

Answer (score 0):

It's very common for ISPs to block outbound connections to port 25 by default. Try using `SMTPSecure = 'tls'` and `Port = 587` - that server definitely responds on that port.

Connection problems are covered in [the PHPMailer docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting).

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that never answered this question, the problem was the time, the function did not have enough time to contact with server. I increased the time in `phpMailer` class and everything went back to work.